# Possibly merge [eclipse-plugin] and [eclipse-plugin-dev]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

I don't quite know what the difference between [eclipse-plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eclipse-plugin) and [eclipse-plugin-dev](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eclipse-plugin-dev) is.  They seem to be similar.

A fair amount of the [eclipse-plugin-dev](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eclipse-plugin-dev) questions are also tagged with [eclipse-plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eclipse-plugin).